# CN1 error: cannot find symbol setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance) in CN1 generated code

Tags: codenameone

This code was working in previous builds and the app code was not changed.  I did work on changes in the theme for adding support for the Facebook/Google logins. In the "DON'T EDIT" code in my CN1 project, I am getting the error;

```
error: cannot find symbol
        setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance
```

The error occurs in multiple locations, but here is the some of the code;

```
    private void initGuiBuilderComponents(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance) {
        guiBuilderBindComponentListeners();
        setLayout(new com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout());
        setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
                setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        setTitle("Processing");
        setName("Processing");
        addComponent(gui_Box_Layout_Y);
                gui_Box_Layout_Y.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
.
.
.
        gui_Table_Layout.addComponent(ButtonAbandonConstraint, gui_ButtonAbandon);
                gui_TextFieldCancelReason.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_TextFieldCancelReason.setName("TextFieldCancelReason");
        gui_TextFieldCancelReason.setRows(2);
        gui_ButtonCancel.setText("Cancel");
                gui_ButtonCancel.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_ButtonCancel.setName("ButtonCancel");
        gui_ButtonPrevious.setText("Previous");
                gui_ButtonPrevious.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_ButtonPrevious.setName("ButtonPrevious");
        gui_ButtonProcess.setText("Process");
                gui_ButtonProcess.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_ButtonProcess.setName("ButtonProcess");
        gui_ButtonNext.setText("Next");
                gui_ButtonNext.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_ButtonNext.setName("ButtonNext");
        gui_ButtonAbandon.setText("Order Abandoned");
                gui_ButtonAbandon.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_ButtonAbandon.setName("ButtonAbandon");
        gui_LabelDrinkNumber.setText("Search");
                gui_LabelDrinkNumber.setInlineStylesTheme(resourceObjectInstance);
.
.
.
```

Comment: Also, is there something I might have done in the theme or gui designer would affect the generated code in a way to generate the "setInlineStylesTheme" lines of code and/or is there a way to force a rebuild of the generated code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your project libs.  Right click project > Properties > Update Project libs.